# Blender room using planes visible in Unity from outside not inside, completely gone in Oculus Rift

Tags: unity

I have created a room in Blender by using a plane, extruding the sides to make the walls. I have set normals to outside, have tried all the settings I can find in people with similar issues, but when I import to Unity, you can see the room from the outside, the floor doesn't seem to exist and when you go inside it is entirely transparent. When I fire up Oculus Rift it is completely gone.

Can anyone suggest a solution. Using Blender 2.83.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you set the normals outside it's this is the expected sight. You are supposed to set them inside or add thicknes to the walls with the Solidify modifier.

Comment: Ah ok, everything I had read online said totally the opposite regarding normals, however I have tried normals inside also and no difference. I will try your suggestion with the Solidify modifier also and report back. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Well this solved the issue in Unity, but, when I view in Oculus it still does not exist.

Comment: Actually what I think is happening is the avatar is falling through it. I have added box collider though.

Comment: The solution to the issue with falling through the plane was to add box collider and mesh collider.